# Displaying the database values?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a beginner in `php/html` and i need your help guys..

I just want to post the `barangay` values which are

```
1- huyon huyon
2- talojongon
```

and when there's the same `barangay` it should only displays as one...not including the disease.

Please help it will be appreciated:This is my current code

status for barangay
receive for disease

SEE THE PICTURES BELOW

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <br><center><h3>TOP DISEASE IN THIS MONTH</h3></center>

        <br>
        <table id="keywords" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th><center>Barangay</th></center>
                    <th><center>Diseases</th></center>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    include 'database.php';
                    $pdo = Database::connect();
                    $sql = 'SELECT * from patients WHERE receive="asd"';
                    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td><center>'. $row['status'] . '</center></td>';
                        echo '<td><center>'. $row['receive'] . '</center></td>';

                    }
                    Database::disconnect();
                ?>
             </tbody>
```

```
    </div></div>
```

```
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="mail.php">Back</a>
                   <a class="btn btn-success" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </p></center>
```

[There are the same barangay huyon huyon so the another must be delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m7xS.png)

[This is my current output..with the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrRPf.png)

Comment: Guys...........

Comment: Btw you forgot the closing `</tr>`

Comment: And also if `receive="asd"` becomes a user input at some point consider using PHP's PDO with SQL-injection free prepared statement. But since your are a beginner you might not be there yet.

Comment: Ok Thank you sebastien..about the closing </tr> :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows

Change your query to

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM patients WHERE Diseases="asd"';
```

Comment: Thanks yousaf ...But nothing's changed..it's the same output again

Comment: @NathanWest There's no column named `recieve` in your table. Change that to `Diseases`

Comment: Thanks yousaf... :)

Comment: But yousaf ..distinct shows the same values only...i want to remove the duplicate..and make it only one yousaf thank you

Comment: @NathanWest `DISTINCT` removes duplicate values. It doesn't shows same values